# Need help in understanding the formal definition of the limit.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definition, riemann-integration

Consider the following definition given by the author of my book:

> The *definite integral* of the function $f(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$ is the limit of the integral sums
>   $$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(\xi_i) \Delta x_i \text{ when }\max |\Delta x_i|\to0.$$

[image]

Where $\xi_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$ and $\triangle x_i=x_i-x_{i-1}$. In order for the Reimann sum to be equal to the actual area under the curve the interval $\triangle x_i$ must become infinitesimaly small. But I don't understand how the notation used by the author conveys this idea. Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $i=1,...,n-1$, the notation $f(\xi_i)\Delta x_i$ can be interpreted as the area of a rectangle of base $\Delta x_i$ and height  $f(\xi_i)$.

Thus, the notation $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(\xi_i)\Delta x_i$ (sum of the areas of the $n-1$ rectangles) can be interpreted as an approximation to the actual area.

As you said, in order this sum to be equal to the actual area, the interval $\Delta x_i$ must become infinitesimally small (for all $i=1,...,n-1)$. This part is covered by the condition $\max|\Delta x_i|\to 0$.

Explicitly, the definition
$$\int_a^bf(x)\;dx=\lim\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(\xi_i)\Delta x_i\text{ when }\max\Delta x_i\to 0$$
means

> For all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
>   $$|x_i-x_{i-1}|<\delta\text{ for all }i=1,...,n-1\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \left|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(\xi_i)\Delta x_i-\int_a^bf(x)\;dx\right|<\varepsilon$$

According to the previous interpretation, this means that if the base of all rectangles are small enough, then the difference between the actual area and the approximation is very small.

Comment: Hi Pedro, thank you for your answer. Actually, this helps me in understanding a problem given by the author in the exercise.

Comment: How would we find $\delta$ if we are given with a value for $\epsilon$?

Comment: @ShreyAryan It depends on the function $f$ and, in general, it is not a easy task.

Comment: @ShreyAryan If it is a exercise, I suggest you post it as a new question with all details.

Comment: how does $\max \triangle x_i$ tending to $0$ ensure that the interval $\triangle x_i$ becomes infinitesimally small?